# Apache - How to find value of SSLMutex

Tags: linux, apache-2.2

With SSLMutex directive configured as default how do I find the value taken by default.

```
default | yes
This directive tells the SSL Module to pick the default locking implementation as determined by the platform and APR.
```

The default of the similar core directive, AcceptMutex, can be discovered by by setting LogLevel to debug.  This does not seem to be the case for the ssl directive.